# Gevents groups vs Gevents pools

Tags: python-3.x, pool, gevent, greenlets

I am beginning to learn about gevents, referring this tutorial : *http://sdiehl.github.io/gevent-tutorial/*.

I can't really understand any major difference between a group of greenlets and a pool of greenlets. Can someone please explain or point to a source where the answer might be documented, preferably with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, they are identically, except:

> A pool is like a group, but the maximum number of members is governed
>   by the *size* parameter.

As you can see in the [sources](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/master/src/gevent/pool.py#L518), a `Pool` inherits from `Group`.